# how to read columns of random spaced data from database export

Tags: sql, csv

I am using Pervasive SQL and the Export wizard does not work. So, my only alternative is to export as text files. The text files that are created are delimited by random amounts of space:

```
 col1          col2                 col3      col4
 (null)        This is some data    123       more data
 (null)        Something else...    435       more stuff
 (null)        Blah blah Blah       324       more data
 (null)        More data            343       more data
 (null)                             432       More stuff
 (null)        Some have none...    543       more data
```

I am having problems trying to find a solid way of converting this to a csv or some other delimited value. Not all columns have data and the data may have different amounts of white space between the values. Any suggestions for parsing this data with software or a library I can use?

Comment: Try looking at the textfile in some program that can show different types of whitespaces represented by different chars, perhaps you will be able to spot a method jn what looks eandom now.

Comment: Suggestion on software?

Comment: I think it's possible in notepad++, but not sure and can't test right now.

Comment: If your values never contain multiple spaces, you could do a global replacement of "2 or more spaces" with a comma.

Comment: Unfortunately that will not work.

Comment: The example that you've shown in the question looks like fixed-width columns. Is it really the case? Then just look at the first line (the header) and determine widths of each column. If columns have varying width, then your sample is misleading. e.g. when you open a text file in Excel it asks whether it is delimited or fixed-width.